# How can i make image processing to varying rate of RGB pixels and read my data?

Tags: android-activity

MY project is to read RGB pixels and translate it to letters data
colors vary between red, green and blue every 3msec
i want to make image processing to these colors and translate it
i use BoofCV to process my data
but the program closed and can't complete processing 
 i don't know what is the problem
can anyone hep me please?

Comment: Can you show what you've got so far? Stackoverflow is not a code writing or architecture service but a Q&A site to help programmers who have concrete problems with code.

Comment: can i write my code here?

Comment: The code is long i don't know what to do
send it here copy and paste 
or send it in compressed file?

Comment: Well you should extract the code that is not doing what you want it to do. So I hope that it is not more then a few dozen lines. Then you edit your question and place it in there.

Comment: can i get your e-mail address to send you all the code

Comment: I can't detect where is the problem in my code
there is no error

Comment: i want to make every letter take 3 or 4 colors ..... as example A take Red Red Red....
when i open my camera and start to process the pixels program can't continue processing or some times process some pixels then close suddenly
i don't know where is the problem
can you help me detect it and solve it?